# Configure PEAR on CentOS 6 and PLESK

Tags: httpd, centos6, pear

I'm hoping to get a little assistance with configuring PEAR to work properly.  I have a PHP file that's calling PEAR's mail and mail-mime files, and I believe I am missing some steps because I keep getting the very common

```
Warning: include_once(Mail.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
Warning: include_once(Mail_Mime/mime.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

It is installed -

```
Installed packages, channel pear.php.net:
=========================================
Package          Version State
Archive_Tar      1.3.7   stable
Console_Getopt   1.2.3   stable
Mail             1.2.0   stable
Mail_Mime        1.8.3   stable
PEAR             1.9.4   stable
Structures_Graph 1.0.4   stable
XML_RPC          1.5.4   stable
XML_Util         1.2.1   stable
```

And according to [this TUT](http://www.matteomattei.com/en/install-yum-and-php-pear-on-centos-5), I need to configure it appropriately in each vhost.  I have already gone through and adjusted the `php.ini` file, but when [the TUT](http://www.matteomattei.com/en/install-yum-and-php-pear-on-centos-5) speaks of the

`php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs:/tmp:/usr/share/pear:/local/PEAR"`

in my `/var/www/vhosts/example.com/conf/httpd.include` file I kind of get lost.  There are several `httpd.include` files in that directory, all preceded with very long numerical strings.

All I want to do is have an email attachment in my form....

Any insight or similar experiences shared would be greatly appreciated.